# How to write recursive lambda expression in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, lambda

I am not sure if this is good programming practice, but I would like to know if one can define a recursive function using the lambda expression.

This is an artificial example I made up: So one can defined the factorial function in Haskell recursively as follows

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer 
factorial 1 = 1
factorial (n + 1) = (n + 1) * factorial n
```

Now, I want a function `f` such that `f n = (factorial n) + 1`. Rather than using a name for `factorial n` (i.e. defining it before hand), I want to define `f` where `factorial n` is given a lambda expression within the definition of `f`. Can I use a recursive lambda definition in `f` in place of using the name factorial?

Comment: [Y-combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator#Y_combinator)

Comment: Why not just give it a name? It doesn't have to be a global name, there's `let` and `where`.

Comment: As an aside, note that `n+k` patterns as used in your definition of `factorial` have been [removed from the language as of Haskell 2010](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_2010). It's advisable to stop using them.

Comment: p.s. I prefer the base case 0: `factorial 0 = 1` which will allow it to work for one more number

Comment: @delnan: I guess you wont like my code since almost all of it imports `Data.Function (fix)`

Comment: @Mehrdad The Y-combinator is not well-typed in Haskell.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The canonical way to do recursion with pure lambda expressions is to use a *fixpoint combinator*, which is a function with the property

```
fixpoint f x = f (fixpoint f) x
```

If we assume that such a combinator exists, we can write the recursive function as

```
factorial = fixpoint (\ff n -> if n == 1 then 1 else n * ff(n-1))
```

The only problem is that `fixpoint` *itself* is still recursive. In the pure lambda calculus, there are ways to create fixpoint combinators that consist only of lambdas, for example the classical "Y combinator":

```
fixpoint f = (\x -> f (x x)) (\x -> f (x x))
```

But we still have problems, because this definition is not well-typed according to Haskell -- and it can be proved that there is *no way* to write a well-typed fixpoint combinator using only lambdas and function applications. It can be done by use of an auxiliary data type to shoehorn in some type recursion:

```
data Paradox a = Self (Paradox a -> a)
fixpoint f = let half (Self twin) = f (twin (Self twin))
             in half (Self half)
```

(Note that if the injections and projections from the singleton data type are removed, this is exactly the Y combinator!)

Comment: Although it does not typecheck, one can still have fun with it! [factorial](http://hpaste.org/steps/50534?expr=fixpoint+fact%27), [factorial 3](http://hpaste.org/steps/50534?expr=fixpoint+fact%27+3) :)

Comment: Is there a reason to use `data` here, or will `newtype` work as well (better)?

Comment: @dfeuer: Probably `newtype` would work better -- I wasn't aware of that language feature when I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, using the fixed-point function [`fix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:fix):

```
fact :: Int -> Int
fact = fix (\f n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * (f (n-1)))
```

Basically, it doesn't have a name, since it's a lambda expression, so you take the function in as an argument. Fix applies the function to itself "infinitely" many times:

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

and is defined in `Data.Function`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do we use lambda's instead of `let in`?

```
Prelude> (let fib n = if n == 1 then 1 else n * fib(n-1) in fib ) 4
24
```

Comment: `let` still requires naming functions.

Answer (score 0):

Owen is spot on with the fix function

```
Prelude> fix f = f (fix f)
Prelude> fix (\f n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * f (n - 1)) 6
720
```

The nameless Lambda function is self terminating even if fix is not.
Owen's fix function beats the fix function typically used in Haskell which is

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let {x = f x} in x
```

Both allow anonymous recursive lambda functions